# Why does "this" inside functions defined in and passed to IIFE's reference the function itself?

Tags: javascript, this, iife

Disclaimer:  I've been warned that this question may be downvoted.  I'd appreciate if you didn't -- I asked my teacher in a Javascript course for the explanation and he didn't know so I thought I'd ask here...

I'm trying to wrap my head around `this` and have been reading Kyle Simpson, but have encountered a case I don't understand.

As I understand it, when you call a function inside another function, if the function is called "standalone" (see Simpson here: [You Don't Know JS: this and Object Prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md)) then `this` should be `Window` (or `undefined` if it in `strict` mode)

```
var fn = function globo () { console.log(this);};

function calling(called) {

console.log(called());

}
calling(fn); // "Window" or "undefined"
```

but if you pass a similar function to an IIFE you get a curious result

```
 function calling(called) {

    console.log(called());

    }(function globo () { console.log(this);}); // [Function: globo]
```

This seems to be a rare case where `this` references the function being called, instead of the "caller" or the default case of where it was defined.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: "_when you call a function inside another function, this takes its scope from where it was defined._" Nope, you'd need an arrow function to achieve this. Notice also, that the second snippet is not an IIFE.

Comment: I'm getting `window` using your IIFE, not `globo`. By the way, your IIFE is missing the first parens.

Comment: `function calling(x) {....}(function globo() { ...})` is syntactically equivalent to `function calling(x) {....}; (function globo() { ...})`, and yields `globo` as its value. `globo` is not getting `console.log`'d, no function is getting executed, it's just console returning the last evaluation's result, as if you wrote `1;2;3` and it'd display `3`. As others already said, you're missing `!`, `+`, `(...)` or some other way of forcing the parser to evaluate this as an IIFE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, that is not a IIFE. In the way you have wrote, you basically have defined a function, `calling`, that **you never call**, and after that, another function, `globo`, that you also never call. If you execute this code in the console, you'll get `globo` as result since that is the value of your last expression – since you used the parenthesis, is not a function declaration.

You can double check running this code instead:

```
 function calling(called) {
    console.log('foo');
 }(function globo () {});
```

You will have likely the same result.

A IIFE would have been:

```
 (function calling(called) {
    console.log(called());
 })(function globo () { console.log(this)});
```

Where, indeed, `this` returns `Window` (or `undefined`).